# Cannot access variable using await-async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried using Async-Await in NodeJs RESTful API but I seem to get an error I cannot resolve.

Here is my `db.js`:

```js
const User = require('../models/User'),
    user = {};

user.findUserByUsername = async function (username) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({username});
        if (user)
            return {data: user, status: 200};

        return {message: `Cannot find user with username: ${username}`, status: 404};
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
};

module.exports = user;
```

And here is my `api.js`:

```js
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    user = require('../db/db');

router.get('/user', async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await user.findUserByUsername(req.query.username);
    //           ^
    //           Cannot access 'user' before initialization

    if (!user.status)
        return next(user);

    res.status(user.status);
    res.doc = user.status === 404 ? user.message : user.data;
    next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

When making a HTTP request, my server is crashing at that point. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You’re declaring `const user`, so access to your outer `const user = require('../db/db')` is shadowed. Use a different variable name. This has nothing to do with `async`–`await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing your variable names up. You have `user` as an import, but you also have `user` as a variable you're trying to assign to as a result of `findUserByUsername`.

Use different variable names, and follow the capitalization convention for this sort of database lookup:

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    User = require('../db/db');

router.get('/user', async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findUserByUsername(req.query.username);
```